# Getting an Element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems that getting an element in AngularJS is a bad idea, i.e. doing something like:

```
$('.myElement')
```

in say, a controller is not an angular way of doing things.

Now my question is, how **should** I get something in angular?

Right now, what I'm doing (and is an accepted way of doing it) is by watching a variable, and my directive does something based on it.

```
scope.$watch('varToWatch', function (varToWatch) {
    if(attrs.id == varToWatch)
    {
         //Run my Directive specific code
    }
});
```

However, while this particular design works for most cases, `watch` is an expensive operation, and having lots of directives watching can really slow down your application.

TL:DR - What is an angular way of getting a directive based on a variable on the directive? (like the one above)?

Comment: There is no generic answer. Angular alternatives to getting the element depend on what are you trying to do. What are you going to do with the element after you get the element if you use jQuery way?

Comment: @RaviH I'm just trying to get it, so I can do operations with it (maybe with it's isolate scope, or maybe animations). Actually, someone in the IRC told me the answer, which required something like Publishing the Variable or something like that, I forgot unfortunately.

Comment: if you want to do animations angular has ngAnimate to help with that. And what you mean by "get a directive based on a variable on the directive", you mean like get the text from directive attribute like `ng-repeat="item in items"` get the `item in items` part?

Comment: @PatrickEvans e.g I want to get directive that has (attrs.id == varToWatch), then do things to it (I am using ngAnimate inside my directive, but I need to get the element)

Comment: When you write a directive, you do not need to get the element, since the code is only run for the element that you have assigned the directive. I agree with @PatrickEvans here; you need to be more specific. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MW. I have a lot of the same directives (therefore the code will run on all of them), but I need to get only one directive from the lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get/set values you don't need to fetch the element using jQuery. Angular data binding is the way to do it.
2. directives is the way to go if you want to do animations or any kind of element attributes and DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically right; the directive should watch something in the `$scope` and perform it's logic when that thing changes. Yes, watch statements are expensive, and that is a problem once your number of watches start to approach ~2000.

Looking at your code though, I see one problem:

1. The variable `$scope.varToWatch` references an id in the template.
2. When this variable changes, you want something to happen to the element which has this id.

The problem here is in the first point: The controller should know *nothing* about the DOM, including the id of any element. You should find another way to handle this, for example:

```
<div my-directive="one"> ... </div>
<div my-directive="two"> ... </div>
<div my-directive="three"> ... </div>
...etc
```

And in your directive:

```
scope.$watch('varToWatch', function (varToWatch) {
    if(attrs.myDirective == varToWatch)
    {
         // Run my Directive specific code
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but could you explain further? I don't understand it, that looks like the way I'm doing it. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are very vague as to what you're trying to achieve, but I'll try to answer in context of your last comment.

> I have a lot of the same directives (therefore the code will run on all of them), but I need to get only one directive from the lot.

You talk a lot about getting the right element. The directive element is passed to the link function in the directive. If you are not using this element (or children of it) directly, but rather trying to search for the element you want somehow, you are most likely approaching the problem the wrong way.

There are several ways to solve this, I'm sure. If you're thinking about animations, there is already support for that in Angular, so please don't try reinvent the wheel yourself. For other logic, here are two suggestions:

### Secondary directive

If the logic you want to apply to this directive is generic, i.e. it could be applied to other directives in your application, you could create a new directive which works together with directives. You can set prioritization in directive in order to control which directive is executed first.

```
<main-directive ... helper-directive="{{condition_for_applying_logic}}"></main-directive>
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7NmDs/1/)

### Expanding main directive

If the logic is tightly coupled to this directive, you can just create a new attribute, either dynamic or static, and bind to it in the directive. Instead of checking 'attrs.id == varToWatch', you check if $scope.apply-logic === 'true' and apply the logic then.

```
<main-directive ...></main-directive>  <!-- Not applied here -->
<main-directive apply-logic="true" ...></main-directive> <!-- Applied here -->
<main-directive apply-logic="{{some.varOnScope}}"...></main-directive> <!-- Conditional -->
```

Please comment if something is unclear.